# Trying to implement hash and salted password into login form

Tags: c#, mysql, hash

I am trying to implement hash and salted password into login form where I have simple mysql connected database containing id-Int, username-VarChar, password-VarChar and salt-VarChar. When i try to debug the program and enter the correct data I am still getting the

> wrong details

show box. By any chance looking at the code bellow do you know where is my mistake and how to solve the problem.

PS: Please note that for "salt" field in my database I try to insert the same data as in password, tried to leave it blanc, try to change it from varchar to Sha1 but still was getting the same error.

```
static byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(string plainText, string salt)
    {
       HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();

       byte[] plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
       byte[] saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

       byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = new byte[plainTextBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];
       saltBytes.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, 0);
       plainTextBytes.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, salt.Length); 

       byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);

       return hash;
    }

        public bool tryLogin(string username , string password)
        {
             using (var con = new MySqlConnection("host=localhost;user=admin;password=password;database=sozopouk_test2;"))
             {
                 con.Open();

                 var salt = string.Empty;

                 using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select salt From niki where user_name = @username", con))
                 {
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

                     salt = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
                 }

                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(salt)) return false;

                 var hashedPassword = GenerateSaltedHash(password, salt);

                 using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM niki WHERE user_name = @username and user_password = @password", con))
                 {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", hashedPassword);

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                         return reader.Read();
                    }
                 }
             }
             }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tryLogin(user.Text, pass.Text) == true)
            {
                MainScreen F2 = new MainScreen();
                F2.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }

             else MessageBox.Show("Wrong details!");
        }
```

Comment: Does the `salt` column in your `niki` table contain a value for the username that you're trying to login as?

Comment: @Bridge the current salt column is empty and is defined as varchar 255

Comment: That's a reason to return false then. Your login method has this code in: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(salt)) return false;`

Comment: @Bridge may be it will sound stupid but what parameters to insert in the salt?

Comment: It looks to me like you've got the username and hashed (and salted) password in the db, and in order to compare the two to see if you've got valid credentials, you're then recalculating the hashed and salted password from the plain text password entered by the user, and the pre-defined salt in the database. If the pre-defined salt for this row in the database is empty, it can't create the salted hash to compare against and login fails. Without the salt value in the column, how did the password get populated in the first place? Do you know what the salt value for this row should be?

Comment: @Bridge No that's what I was wondering if I have ti insert something in the database do I have to converted and if yes how? Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your problem. (Just the Hash algorithm)
It seems that this line is not right

```
plainTextBytes.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, salt.Length);
```

Instead you should use

```
plainTextBytes.CopyTo(plainTextWithSaltBytes, saltBytes.Length);
```

However this gives me an exception not a false on reader.Read.
So it's possible that the problem is something different. 
You should try in debug to stop the program before the reader. 
Read and check the values of @username and @password.
With that info, using your preferred MySql Manager, check if the User table contains exactly the values in the parameters.

Comment: replace the code that you produce but still getting **Wrong error** Any idea?

PS: Should I leave the salt field empty and defined as varchar?

Comment: Have you regenerated the user passwords with the algorithm change? Have you checked in debug if a user with the hashed password exists? Here there is a samples that explain in details how to [generate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602(v=CS.70).aspx) Hashpassword